# Write a query for SOLR to exclude a some results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

Actually I am searching a string `kalyana mandap` and for this I am expecting the following results:
  I want a results which does not contains `kalyana mandap` as pharse but the result should contains `kalyana and mandap` and `kalyana or mandap`

For this I have written the following query:

```
`kalyana mandap NOT "kalyana mandap"`
```

But its not giving the results which contains the both the word in the documents. How to modify the query for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'kalyana OR mandap NOT "kalyana mandap"'
```

Comment: Updated answer. OR should return documents when either Or both words are present. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you show the complete solr query? What is the default search field? I ran the same query on an existing index and I am getting the desired results for a similar query. How many results are you returning? Please note that documents which have both the terms will be ranked higher. If you are only looking at the top 10 rows (which is the solr default), you might not see documents which have only either of the terms.